70 nations vs 70 who went down to Egypt
What's the connection between the 70 nations and the 70 descendants of Yaacov who went to Egypt? Is there a 1:1 correllation anywhere?

https://www.sefaria.org/Rabbeinu_Bahya,_Bamidbar_11.16.3 has the correlation

@אילפא I also always wondered about the source for this. Thank you for suggesting the place to start looking.

Yes, This is a general paradigm that G-d established at the beginning of Creation.
In the creation of the Hebrew Aleph-Beit, the 22 letters, there are 3 general categories, 3 Amot (אמות which are אמ׳ש, which establish right ימין, left שמאל and center אמצע, as well as beginning ראש, end סוף and between תוך), 7 Kefulot (כפולות meaning doubling letters), and 12 Peshutot (פשוטות which are הוזחטילמנסע׳ק) which correspond to the major constellations and the dimension of time, like the 12 hours of day and 12 hours of night.
This follows the tradition which the patriarch Avraham received from Adam HaRishon (who received it from the Angel, Raziel) and his descendants and is recorded in Sefer Yetzirah.
The seven doubling letters (בג׳ד-כפר׳ת) establish the doubling relationship on what is described as the side of Holiness and its opposite.
The 70 souls of Israel are the side of Holiness and are the parallel to the 70 nations (who are actually manifestations of the 70 Ministering Angels who are their spiritual source.)
If you would like two excellent early sources that discuss this about the letters and the paradigm, see Sefer Ma'arechet HaElokut and Sefer Ginat Egoz, section 2, by Rabbi Yosef Gikatilla, who was a student of Rabbi Avraham Abulafia.

Checkmark coming your way in a couple of days, (as recommended by site policy), unless someone manages to come up with a better answer, if such a thing can be imagined!

@RabbiKaii You know, because of the awards the last couple of weeks, I had a question. I have never been credited with a gold badge and the message on the gold badge is telling me to write an answer that receives 100 points to get my first. I've had tons of answers over the years with more than 10 up votes and no down votes. So any of them should have gotten gold badges. And I also have numerous answers with correct and bonus scores that are way over 100 points. Why have I never been credited with the gold badges?

To get a gold badge for a particular tag, it has 2 conditions, one is to get 1000 points for all your answers and questions combined. So, for badges, 1 point = 1 overall upvote, (I had to get 100 overall upvotes to get my 100 points for the bronze). I think that's why, you'll need an answer with 100 upvotes overall (i.e. subtract any downvotes). That's pretty hard to do, not sure any answer or question on this site has that many? What gold badge are you talking about?

I don't really understand all this badge stuff. The message is the following: "You don’t have a gold badge yet. Write an answer that scores 100 or more to earn your first." If I take that at the plain meaning, it means any answer that scores 100 or more earns a gold badge.

This: https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/25/great-answer. It's talking in lashon benei adam: i.e. how it appears on the screen (see this recently awarded: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67788589/6938505), not k'pshuto "score". Note: There are other gold badges, doesn't have to be that one: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=general&filter=gold (I was right, it says there that Great Answer was never awarded on Mi Yodeya)

@RabbiKaii The "Great Answer" badge, a gold badge that can be awarded multiple times, and has apparently never been awarded, says this: "Answer score of 100 or more. This badge can be awarded multiple times.". I have numerous answers that have met this requirement including recently. That suggests that it is set up incorrectly. That's why it has never been awarded. "Awarded 0 times." The requirement for this gold badge is found: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/badges/40/great-answer

I tried to follow the advice of אילפא and look in Rabbeinu Bachya. Sefer Sitrei Rabbeinu Bachya, parashas Vayigash (Bereshis 46:15) states

וחיזקיר כל השבעים בלשון נפש וכו' נגד ע' המלאכים הסובבים כסא הכבוד הניקראים בית דינו כדלקמן. ועמ"ש רבינו ז"ל בפרשת בשלח ע"פ ויבואו אילימה
And he mentioned all 70 people using the term nefesh etc. The 70 souls [who descended with Yaakov to Egypt] correspond to the Throne of Glory, which is called G-d's Court of Justice, as we explained earlier. And look up what Rabbeinu Bachya wrote in parashas Beshalach, the comment on words And they came to Eylim (Shemos 15:27)

If we look up Rabbenu Bachya Shemos 15:27 (midrash, and kabbala), we find an extended comment of which the comment of Rabbeinu Bachya Bamidbar 11:16 is just a summary. It indeed explains the connection:

וע"ד המדרש שתים עשרה עינות מים ושבעים תמרים, רבי אליעזר המודעי אומר מיום שברא הקב"ה את עולמו ברא שם י"ב מבועין כנגד י"ב שבטי ישראל ושבעים דקלים כנגד שבעים זקנים. באור המדרש הזה כי מעת שנסעו ישראל מים סוף לא באו למקום טוב עד שהגיעו כאן באלים וכשם שנעשה להם נס על הים במתיקות מימיו ובשנים עשר גזרים לי"ב שבטים כן היה בכאן באלים היו מימיו מתוקים מים חיים נוזלים וי"ב מבועין לי"ב שבטים וכן שבעים דקלים לשבעים זקנים כדי לחלוק כבוד לכל שבט ושבט וכן לכל אחד ואחד מהזקנים.
A Midrashic approach (Mechilta Yayissa section 1) on the words “12 springs of water and seventy date-palms.” Rabbi Eliezer Hamodai said that from the day G’d had created the universe He had created 12 springs of water corresponding to the 12 tribes of Israel. He had also planted 70 date-palms corresponding to the seventy elders of the Jewish people. The meaning of this Midrash is that after the crossing of the Sea of Reeds the Israelites had not encountered such a good camping place as this one at Eylim. Just as they had experienced a miracle at the sea when G’d sweetened the salt-water of the sea so that they could drink from it while crossing, and He provided 12 lanes for the different tribes to cross in, so this type of miracle was re-enacted at Eylim. Its waters were sweet and flowing; there were 12 separate springs so that each tribe could have its own water supply. The seventy date-palms corresponded to the seventy elders each of whom was accorded honour in his own right.
וע"ד הקבלה ויבאו אילמה ושם י"ב עינות מים ושבעים תמרים בבאם עתה במקום הזה באלים נכנסו באותה השגה הנקראת אלהים וזהו לשון ויבאו אילמה ושם שתים עשרה עינות מים כי השיגו שם י"ב מלאכים שלשה לכל רוח מד' רוחות העולם וכל שלשה מהם עם צבאותיהם מחנה גדול והם הנקראים ד' מחנות שכינה, ושבעים תמרים הם ע' מלאכים הסובבים כסא הכבוד וממונים על ע' אומות שבעולם כל אחד ואחד ממונה על אומתו, וכן תמצא בספר הבהיר ומאי ושם י"ב עינות מים הקב"ה נתנם להם בתחלה עינות מים אח"כ החזירם להם אבנים, דכתיב (יהושע צ ט) ושתים עשרה אבנים, מה טעם מפני שבתחלה היתה התורה בעולם נמשלת למים ואח"כ נקבעה במקום קבוע מה שאין המים עושים כן שהיום כאן ומחר כאן. ומה שבעים תמרים מלמד ששבעים קומות יש להקב"ה ושואבים מי"ב פשוטות, מה המים הללו פשוטים אף הם פשוטים, ומנא לן דתמר הוי קומה דכתיב (שיר ז) זאת קומתך דמתה לתמר ולא עוד אלא בתמרים יש שבעים מינים דכתיב ושבעים תמרים ולא היו דומים זה לזה ופעולות זה אינו דומה לזה וטעם זה אינו דומה לזה ע"כ, ולפי שכל אחד ואחד פועל מנויו כמו שנתמנה עליו ואיננו רשאי ליכנס לגבול חברו ולכך אמר אינם דומין זה לזה ולא פעולתו של זה דומה לפעולתו של זה, ונרמז לך בזה כי מי"ב עינות אלה שהם ד' מחנות שכינה שואבים בה שבעים תמרים הם המלאכים הסובבים כסא הכבוד המשילום בתמרים על שם הקומה, והנה דוגמתם יצאו מיעקב י"ב שבטים הנחלקים לד' מחנות ומהם היו שבעים נפש, והבן זה המעט ותמצא מעלת יעקב שנקרא אל, כענין שכתוב (בראשית לג) ויקרא לו אל אלהי ישראל, ודרשו רז"ל מי קראו אל אלהי ישראל, ותדע ותשתכל כל עניני האבות ומצות התורה הכל ציורים ודוגמא למצוא ולדעת דעת קדושים.
A kabbalistic approach: the words “they came to Eylim where there were twelve springs of water and seventy date-palms“ mean that when the Israelites now arrived at this site they attained a certain spiritual level called “elohim” (play on the word אלימה with the letters re-arranged). The 12 fountains are a simile for 12 angels, three from each of the four directions. Each group of three angels was accompanied by an army of minor angels so that between them all they represented the מחנה שכינה, the camp of the Divine presence supported at four corners with its celestial entourage.
The seventy date-palms represent the seventy angels who surround the throne of G’d’s glory and who are assigned, one each, as the celestial representatives of the 70 nations of the world. You find this confirmed in the Sefer Habahir items 165-7. The author there asks: “what was the significance of the twelve fountains? First G’d gave the Israelites 12 fountains. These were exchanged later when the Jewish people crossed the Jordan into the twelve stones Joshua erected there (Joshua 4,9). The reason is that originally the Torah was likened to life-giving water seeing the Torah, i.e. its bearers were on the move, just like the waters issuing from fountains are on the move, their waters constantly flowing. Once the Israelites crossed the Jordan and began to conquer the Holy Land Torah found a permanent home, was stationary.
As far as the 70 date-palms are concerned, this is a symbol for seventy different קומות, conduits, by means of which G’d dispenses His largess. These draw their input from twelve of the “simple” letters in the alpha-bet. Just as these waters are ordinary waters (of terrestrial origin), so the seventy nations are essentially terrestrial in nature. Whence do we know that a date-palm may be equated with a קומה? We base this on Song of Songs 7,8 זאת קומתך דמתה לתמר, “such is your stature, likened to a towering palm tree.” Not only that but there are 70 different species of palm trees; this is meant by our verse speaking about seventy palm trees. The words ושבעים תמרים mean that each one was different from the other and the fruit they produced were different from one another, each tasting differently. So far Sefer Habahir. [Levush Orah by R' Mordechai Jaffe, in his super-commentary on Rashi, and Menachem Rekanati explain many of these concepts in greater depth. Ed.] It is important to remember that each date-palm had been assigned its task in nature and each had to contribute according to its specific task. It was not in order for them to be grafted one to another to produce new mutations. The entire phenomenon is reminiscent of Yaakov and his twelve sons and the seventy descendants who arrived in Egypt. They were likened to towering palm trees due to their spiritual stature. At the same time they drew their inspiration from Yaakov’s twelve sons who in turn drew theirs from their patriarch-father. The 12 tribes were divided into four camps of three tribes each, encamped in the four directions of the globe enclosing (protecting) the encampment of the Shechinah. This made them carriers of the Divine Presence, Shechinah. This is all reflected in the fact that the patriarch Yaakov himself was called א-ל אלו-הי ישראל, (Genesis 33,20) which line is explained in Megillah 18 as “who called him א-ל? None other than the אלו-הי ישראל, the G’d of Israel.” All of the foregoing only serves the purpose of giving us an inkling of the spiritual stature of our patriarchs.

Thus the source of all this is Sefer haBahir 167. Rabbeinu Bachya's translation covers well paragraphs 165-6 but the statement in 167 is like this:

ואמרת שבעים תמרים שבעים קומות, והא אמרת שבעים ושתים, אלא שבעים ואחת הם וישראל שבעים ושתים אך אינם בכלל, והא אמרת שבעים, אלא האחד שר השטן:
(Translation by R' Aryeh Kaplan) You said that seventy date palms represent the seventy Structures. But have you not said that there are 72? There are 71. Israel makes 72, but it is not included. But did you not say there were seventy? One is the Officer of Satan.

Afterwards there is a mashal about Satan, which is not related to the question.
Thus the connection is learned from the lofty status that Israel achieved by travelling to Eylim. This lofty status modeled the Throne of Glory of HKBH, where the 70 ministering angels represent the 70 nations of the world. The 70 palms, which hinted to those angels, in the camp of Israel made correspondence to the 70 elders of Jewish people, who in turn were representative of the 70 souls that descended to Egypt.
